# parse error on apk install - ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying to install an apk on my android but I get a parse error.
This is my first app so ask for more info if I'm missing something.

```
Phone: Galaxy S2
Android ver: 4.0.4.
App framework: Ionic
App to install: tabs (from the demos. http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)
Android sdk info:
Android build tools 22
Android 4.0.3 (API 15)
OS: OSX 10 El Capitan
```

I guess the app might not be compatible with the android version, but I don't know how to check what. I can't find an earlier version than 19 of the build tools. This looks like a simple app which doesn't need advanced features. Where can I find some clues (error messages, logs, etc...)?

Comment: what is the parse error?

Comment: Parse error: There was a problem parsing the package.

Just that. Can I look somewhere for more info?

Comment: This is a JS console error? Check your `config.xml` for the minimum supported Android version. Also consider the possibility you might have a corrupted download. You might want to try running `ionic start myApp tabs` in a fresh directory because it should work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @Huey, the config.xml was the problem. It had minimum sdk version 16, and I needed 15.

Comment: And for some reason I can't mark your response as the correct answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check your `config.xml` for the minimum Android version you're supporting. The syntax is:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="18" />     

<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" />
```

You could specify this in your Android manifest but including it in `config.xml` is preferred and more convenient.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your config.xml for the minimum Android version you're supporting. The syntax is:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="18" />
```

Answer (score 0):

check your app id
i having same issue
after i edit app id from
“SmartApp.app.com”
to
“com.SmartApp.app.com”
app id must start with com